# Python Timezone format not converting

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone

It seems that my format is incorrect regarding the timezone name.

My end requirement is that I need to parse the following string into a datetime object.

```
import datetime
sometime2 = "Mon Oct 29 14:28:32 MDT 2018"
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(sometime2,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
print(dt.day, dt.year, dt.month, dt.hour, dt.minute)
```

However, the timezone is causing an issue:

> ValueError: time data 'Mon Oct 29 14:28:32 MDT 2018' does not match
>   format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'

The documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) says that %Z is for the timezone name, but I'm erroring.

Does anyone know what format string I need to pass in order to create the datetime object?

EDIT: It seems the %Z matches a limited amount of timezone names. So, in order to convert my string to a datetime object, I need to either convert my timezone name into its offset or some other approach.

Essentially, this question boils down to how can I convert the timezone name to its offset? The requirements of this question is that I'm given the following format (not provided the offset).

Comment: I'm assuming `MDT` is not a valid timezone string (daylight savings).  I'd suggest using `%z` and `-0600`

Comment: So, as @Fabre pointed out, %Z matches a limited amount of timezones. However, due to my constraints, I'm only provided the timezone name. Is there any effective way to convert a timezone name into its corresponding offset?